# OpenLDAP - What is the LDAP proper procedures used for authentication and the usage of field shadowexpire

Tags: ldap, openldap

Question 1:

I'm trying to understand the proper way to use OpenLDAP for user authentication (e.g through form based authentication)

Initial understanding.
1. Set up admin user for OpenLDAP
2. Created user id ClientA/PWDA on OpenLDAP (LDIF)
3. Using form based authentication ClientA login using that credential
4. Web component will use admin user to login to OpenLDAP and verify ClientA credential

The above means ClientA is never login to OpenLDAP. It's the admin user being login and then verify ClientA credential in OpenLDAP.

This seems more logical. If ClientA credential is authenticated through actual logging into OpenLDAP, essentially this means ClientA is being treated as a developer himself. Sure ClientA access can be control through ACL but that's not the point here.

So which should be the correct way to authenticate a client on OpenLDAP.
1. Using admin user logging into OpenLDAP and then verify ClientA credential or
2. Using ClientA credential to test if the credential can login.

If the answer is 2) then this leads to question 2.

Question 2:

1. Using admin user login, the attribute shadowexpire being set to yesterday date/time for ClientA
2. Re-login as ClientA/PWDA
3. ClientA is able to login.

Shouldn't ClientA not allowed to login since the shadowexpire attributes has it set to yesterday date?

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is (2), but `shadowexpire` Is only an object attribute. OpenLDAP itself doesn't care what you do to it. If you want something that OpenLDAP will enforce, see the `ppolicy` overlay.